# Error en actualizar Registro duplicado

Tags: laravel, validación

Estoy tratando de realizar un Update de un registro de mi tabla Sucursals, pero no logro hacer pasar el request de validacion, me dice que el nombre ya se encuentra registrado, y si, pero por ese mismo registro.

Adjunto mi Request de validacion

```
public function rules()
{
    return [
        'name'      =>  'required|unique:sucursals,name',
    ];
}
```

Pero no pasa

Comment: Si, utlizo un controlador de resource

public function update(SucursalUpdate $request, $id)
    {
        $sucursal = Sucursal::find($id);

        $sucursal->name = $request->name;
        $sucursal->estado = $request->estado;

        $sucursal->save();
        return redirect()->route('sucursales.index')->with('info','La sucursal fue actualizada correctamente');
    }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Acabo de encontrar la solución

```html
<?php

namespace App\Http\Requests;


use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\FormRequest;
use Illuminate\Validation\Rule;

class SucursalUpdate extends FormRequest
{
    /**
     * Determine if the user is authorized to make this request.
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function authorize()
    {
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Get the validation rules that apply to the request.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            'name'      =>  'required',
            Rule::unique('sucursals')->ignore($this->id)
        ];
    }
}
```

Esto de RULE es nuevo, anteriormente se utilizaba de otra forma, pero en las nuevas versiones de laravel se utiliza la clase RULE

Answer (score 1):

Basándome en la documentación de Laravel, en tu archivo `Request` necesitas importar *si es que no existe* la clase `Rule` así:

```
use Illuminate\Validation\Rule;
```

Una vez hecho lo anterior, vamos a reemplazar el uso de `unique` por dicha clase e indicarle que parámetro de la `URL` es el que va a ignorar, de este modo:

```
Validator::make($sucursal, [
    'name' => [
        'required',
        Rule::unique('tabla')->ignore($sucursal->name)
    ],
]);
```

- De modo que le indicamos que vamos a aplicar una regla de unicidad sobre la tabla `users` *por ejemplo*
- Pero vamos a ignorar si existe un nombre duplicado **(en una actualización)**, ya que `unique` de forma inicial busca si ya existe un registro con ese valor **(cuando insertamos)** e impide un nuevo registro con el mismo valor.

**Referencias**

- [Reglas de validación](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/validation#available-validation-rules)