# validar email con from request laravel

Tags: laravel

Saludos comunidad estoy intentando validar el email. Tengo un formulario de clientes el cual tiene un campo para ingresar el email, el problema esta al momento de crear un cliente si ingreso un email que ya se encuentra registrado lo toma igual, en este caso lo tendría que rechazar, porque sucede esto?

este es mi contralor:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Http\Requests\SaveClientRequest;
use App\Client;
use App\Company;
use DataTables;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class ClientController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Store a newly created resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function store(SaveClientRequest $request)
    {
        if ($request->ajax()){
            try {
                // utiliza transacciones
                DB::beginTransaction();

                $this->authorize('create', new Client);

                $client = Client::create($request->all());

                $company = $client->company()->create([
                    'name_company'  => $request['name_company'],
                    'cuit'          => $request['cuit'],
                    'web'           => $request['web'],
                    'phone_company' => $request['phone_company'],                   
                    'client_id'     => $client->id
               ]);

                DB::commit();

            } catch (Exception $e) {
                // anula la transacion
                DB::rollBack();
            }
        }        
    }



    /**
     * Update the specified resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \App\Client  $client
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function update(SaveClientRequest $request, $id)
    {        
        if ($request->ajax()){
            try {
                // utiliza transacciones
                DB::beginTransaction();



                $client = Client::with('company')->findOrFail($id); 

                $this->authorize('update', $client);                

                $client->update($request->all()); 
                // $client->fill($request->all());

                $company = $client->company()->update([
                    'name_company'  => $request['name_company'],
                    'cuit'          => $request['cuit'],
                    'web'           => $request['web'],
                    'phone_company' => $request['phone_company'],                   
                    'client_id'     => $client->id
                ]);

                DB::commit();

            } catch (Exception $e) {
                // anula la transacion
                DB::rollBack();
            }
        }              
    }

}
```

**Actualizado**

Esto debería funcionar en mi archivo formRequest, pero no encuentro resultado.
Con estas modificaciones puedo actualizar el cliente sin problemas, pero persiste el error al crear un nuevo cliente si el email ya se encuentra registrado lo acepta igual

```
    {
        return [            
            'name_company'  => 'required|string|min:3|max:50',
            'name_client'   => 'required|string|min:3|max:50',
            'lastname'      => 'required|string|min:3|max:50', 
            'cuit'          => 'required|string',           
            'phone_client'  => 'required|string',
            'email'         => 'required|string|email|max:255',
                            Rule::unique('clients')->ignore($this->id)
        ];                  
    }
```

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [Error en actualizar Registro duplicado](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/309027/error-en-actualizar-registro-duplicado)

Comment: Saludos @Aprendiz he actualizado mi pregunta puedes mirarla?

Comment: podrian indicarme cual es mi error ?

Comment: ¿Podría ser que en la regla para la validación del email tuvieras que indicarle la condición?
`'email' => 'required|string|email|max:255',
                            Rule::unique('clients')->whereNotIn('email', [$this->email])` Por cierto esta validación deberías aplicarla para crear, si tratas de editar datos pasando el mismo email no pasaría.

Comment: Por cierto, la versión de Laravel que usas debería ir siempre en la pregunta, puede ser importante. https://laravel.com/api/5.7/Illuminate/Validation/Rules/Unique.html

Comment: @Orici  gracias por contestar pero mira mi respuesta, lo pude resolver de la siguiente manera

Answer (score 0):

En mi archivo formRequest con estos cambios que realice puedo validar un email, es decir puedo registrar uno nuevo, valida que sea unico en la tabla clientes, y en el caso de actualizar un cliente no genera problemas con el email que le pertenece. Espero le sirva a alguien que lo requiera en su aplicacion.

```
 public function rules()
    {
        $rules = [
            'name_company'  => 'required|string|min:3|max:50',
            'name_client'   => 'required|string|min:3|max:50',
            'lastname'      => 'required|string|min:3|max:50', 
            'cuit'          => 'required|string',           
            'phone_client'  => 'required|string'
        ];

        // Si es diferente a Post
        if($this->method() !== 'PUT')
        {
            $rules ['email' ] = 'required|string|email|max:255|unique:clients,email,' . $this->id;

        }

        return $rules;      

    }
```

Comment: Es interesante la posibilidad de **aplicar distintas reglas de validación conforme al método de la petición** (POST | PUT).